# Does android have a simple way to print a PDF document?

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I know android has `http://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html` and `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html` but I'm wondering if anyone has found an easier way to print a PDF document. My app has PDF documents readily available but no easy access to the page count. Android OS requests pages to be printed from your PDF document. Has anyone found a succinct way to just hand Android OS their PDF document for printing?